# Prolog - Ran into an issue

Tags: prolog

```
minu('-').
minu('+').
minu('/').

f(A):-
   atom_chars(A,X),
   write(X),
   fun(X).

fun([]).

fun([A]):-
   not(minu(A)).

fun([Hd|Tail]):-
   not(minu(Hd)),
   fun(Tail).
```

I am trying to make an function "f" that takes a string and returns True if "-", "+" or "/" are not in it.

But as soon as I use recursive call. It just returns false.

EDIT ::

SOLUTION FOUND ::

Thank you, lurker... And thank you, Daniel Lyons...
I apologize it has been a long day learning Prolog... I ought to go get some sleep.

```
f(A):-
 atom_chars(A,X),
 write(X),
 fun(X).

fun([]).

fun([A]):-
 not(minu(A)).

fun([Hd|Tail]):-
 not(minu(Hd)),
 fun(Tail).
```

Comment: Please show example queries with desired results.

Comment: query : f("a+a") Desired result False.

Comment: And that query should fail, right?

Comment: query f("A*A") Desired result True, because nor '-' , '+' or '/' are in the string

Comment: Your `fun/1` predicate will only succeed if the argument consists *only of* -`, `+`, or `/`, or it will succeed if it gets an empty list. Anything else will fail. Read your predicate carefully.

Comment: Sorry. I just forgot to add write not()'s here. But I edited first post to match the code with the code I am having problems with.

Comment: Your updated code yields true for `f("A*A").` and false for `f("A+A").`. I don't see what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd try this:

```
minu('-').
minu('+').
minu('/').

f(A) :- 
  atom_chars(A, Chars),
  \+ (minu(Op), memberchk(Op, Chars)).
```

By the way, it's important to note that Prolog will not "return" anything; it will either tell you `true` or `false` if the goal succeeds or not, so for instance:

```
?- f("this is a string").
true.

?- f("this i-a string").
false.

?- f("this i+a string").
false.
```

Comment: Thank you! It is a solution to this problem, but I am trying to learn Prolog... :D So I still want to find out why my code does not work.

Comment: Your code does work, at least under SWI. But I would caution you that your `fun([A])` rule is unnecessary (that's why you get two solutions instead of one) and `not(X)` is not ISO so it may not work depending on the implementation of Prolog.